# How to get grayscale image,pixel matrix values within the [0-255] range python

Tags: python, opencv

I am a newbie i am trying to access pixel value of a grayscale image

here goes my code

```
im = cv.LoadImage("new.bmp")
# displaying the matrix form of image
for i in range(im.height):
 for j in range(im.width):
    print im[i,j],

print "\n",i
```

I am getting in output for every pixel values of RGB see the snapshot of the output

[image]

Comment: Convert the image to the gray-scale.!!

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: The image is a grayscale image. I think output should contain only 1 values intead of 3 values

Comment: @Raghib When i look at the output each vector as same values are being written in the vector.!!

Comment: @Arjun  if you have grayscale 120, it translates to RGB (120, 120, 120).The quick and dirty approach is to repeat the grayscale intensity for each component of RGB.

Comment: @RaghibAhsan I don't think it translates.!! I work on c++ but not good with python.!!

Comment: You're loading the image in 3 channel BGR. You can load the image directly in 1 channel grayscale as `img = cv2.imread("path_to_image", 0)`. It should work also with `cv.LoadImage("path_to_image", 0)`

Comment: @Miki thanks you could have provided answer to this question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of OpenCV 2 and 3, `LoadImage()` has been discontinued. Please use the latest version of OpenCV and `imread()` instead.

**Usage-**

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("new.bmp", 0) #since the image is grayscale, we need only one channel and the value '0' indicates just that
for i in range (img.shape[0]): #traverses through height of the image
    for j in range (img.shape[1]): #traverses through width of the image
        print img[i][j]
```

**Documentation:** http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Comment: more: `img[i][j]` and `img[i, j]` are the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all Use latest Opencv 3. to convert the image to grayscale and print the pixel values follow this code

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread("\Test.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#You can directly use gray = cv2.imread("\Test.jpg", 0) for input grayscale image
print(gray)
```